# Symfony : "if" does not work in a twig template

Tags: symfony, if-statement, twig

I'm trying to validate the size of an array before print a value, but the if instruction doesn't work. Always pass thought the if.

This is my code:

```
{% set size = custodian.phoneNumbers|length  %}
{% if size > 3 %}
    {% block phone_number3 %}{{phoneNumbers[2].phoneNumber }}{% endblock %}
{% endif %}
```

size is equal to 2

I try with this code and does not work as well.

```
{% set size = true %}
    {% if size == false %}
        {{size}} 
{% endif %}
```

Please help!!!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answers myself

The block should be outside of the if.

```
{% block phone_type3 %}
    {% if size >= 3 %}
        {{ custodian.phoneNumbers[2].phoneType.value }}:
    {% else %}
        :
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
{% block phone_number3 %}
    {% if size >= 3 %}
        <b>{{ custodian.phoneNumbers[2].phoneNumber }}</b>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: You shoudl accept your own answer, it is indexed in Google and just saved me throwing my laptop out of the window...This issue is also present with variables passed in from the controller. Sigh. This means I have to have the block present even if I don't want to.